# Trying to save time input into mysql database using django

Tags: python, django, forms

i am trying to save data from HTML input into MySql database using Django. Other forms that i created work. My conclusion is that it doesn't work because of time input. I have it converted into datettime python type which should make it work but it still doesn't save. Would you please check my code and see what can be possible the reason for it not saving?

views.py file:

```
def employee_view(request):
    table = employeeModel.objects.all()
    context = {"table": table}
    if request.method == "POST":
        postCopy = request.POST.copy() # to make it mutable
        postCopy['barberStartTime'] = datetime.strptime('15/05/22 ' + postCopy['barberStartTime'], '%d/%m/%y %H:%M').time()
        postCopy['barberEndTime'] = datetime.strptime('15/05/22 ' + postCopy['barberEndTime'], '%d/%m/%y %H:%M').time()
        request.POST = postCopy
        form = employeeForm(request.POST or NONE)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return render(request, 'accounts/employee.html', context)
    return render(request, 'accounts/employee.html', context)
```

python employeeModel:

```
class employeeModel(models.Model):
    barberName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    barber_workplace = models.ForeignKey(workplacesModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    barberStartTime = models.TimeField()
    barberEndTime = models.TimeField()
    class barbers:
        db_table = "home_employeemodel"
```

python employeeForm:

```
class employeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    barberStartTime = forms.TimeField(widget=forms.TimeInput(format='%H:%M:%S'))
    barberEndTime = forms.TimeField(widget=forms.TimeInput(format='%H:%M:%S'))
    class Meta:
        model = employeeModel
        fields = ["barberName", "barber_workplace", "barberStartTime", "barberEndTime"]
```

html input form: (it is part of a table - reason for tr/td tags):

```
<tr>
    <form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        <td class="id-td" scope="row">---</td>
        <td class="barberName-td"><input type="text" name="barberName" placeholder="Meno"/></td>
        <td class="barberWorkplace-td"><input type="number" name="barberWorkplace" placeholder="Mesto"/></td>
        <td class="barberStartTime-td"><input type="time" name="barberStartTime"/></td>
        <td class="barberEndTime-td"><input type="time" name="barberEndTime"/></td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-secondary">Pridať</button></td>
    <form>
</tr>
```

Comment: Models,Forms,ModelForms etc. which are classes, must be written in `PascalCase` not `camelCase` and models doesn't require `Model` to be the suffix, only class based views and forms requires `View` and `Form` to be the suffix respectively.

Comment: Thanks for this, i corrected it in my project. Sorry for lacking knowledge about correct formatting. I pretty much learned all this by myself. But even if i still correct it, it doesn't solve my problem with not saving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i finally figured out where the mistake was. The problem was incorrectly named input for barber workplace. It was named barberWorkplace while it should have been named barber_workplace.